# Can't generate signed APK on Android Studio 3.1

Tags: java, android, gradle, apk, android-studio-3.0

It says:
Could not download lint-gradle.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.1.1): No cached version available for offline mode

Comment: You will need to provide more details to get help. A code sample and details about your environment are a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

> you need to turn on gradle and rebuild application, in order to do
>   this: File-->Settings -->Build, Executions, Deployment --> Build Tools
>   --> Gradle --> uncheck the "offline work" --> click on the apply button --> rebuild your application

[Potentialrepeat question from github bugs](https://github.com/udacity/ud839_Miwok/issues/9)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

uncheck it,close offline mode.